# How i can use this command of Imagemagick in a batch file process?

Tags: batch-file, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

im trying to add a caption below each image using the following Imagemagick command:

```
convert 3_1.jpg   -background Khaki  label:"@3_1.txt" -gravity Center -append 3_1_text.png
```

This works fine and got this:

[figure with label below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIeCR.jpg)

Basically i use an image file named e.g. xxx.jpg and add the caption from a text file with the same name (xxx.txt).
What i want to do now is the same process but for a bunch of jpg files in a folder, using a batch process. I have the following folder:

[folder with JPGs and text files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6M5b.png)

So i want to make a batch file that process each image with his respective txt file, and ideally save all the outputs in a specific directory.

Thank you in advance, and best regards,

Jorge

Comment: Simple for command to iterate all the files in a directory: `FOR %%G IN (*.jpg) DO command`.  The variable `%%G` will hold the file name.

Comment: The simple solution as suggested by Squashman is: `for %%G in (*.jpg) do "C:\ImageMagick\Path\convert.exe" "%%G" -background Khaki label:"@%%~nG.txt" -gravity Center -append "%%~nG_text.png"`

Answer (score -1):

i modified the code of the third answer and it did the job:

```
@ECHO OFF FOR %%G IN (*.jpg) DO convert %%G   -background Khaki  label:"@%%~nG.txt" -gravity Center -append "%%~nG_text.png"
```

it works like charm!

Comment: If any JPEG file contains a space or one of these characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~`` it would not work anymore like a charm. Why have you not used exactly the code as posted by me with `"C:\ImageMagick\Path\convert.exe"` modified to the full qualified file name (drive+path+name+extension) of `convert` on your hard disk enclosed in `"`?

Comment: ah. i simply wanted to maintain my style of code for no particular or important reason. Didnt know about the space or special characters case situation, however, all the JPEG that i will use dont have spaces or the special characters. Anyways, ty for the acclaration! Really appreciated! c: